# RouterServiceProvider from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Previously i have this code working in laravel 5.2

RouterServiceProvider

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    // Model binding
    $router->model('house', 'App\house');

}
```

and in controller

```
public function show(House '$house')
{
        return view('house.show', compact('house'));
}
```

and when i upgrade to Laravel 5.4 this code doesn't work.
So i change my code to this in RouterServiceProvider

```
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();
    Route::model('house', App\House::class);
}
```

But I dont know what to change in the controller codes below

```
public function show(House '$house')
{
        return view('house.show', compact('house'));
}
```

, when I run the code I got this error
    ***(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''$house'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)***

I need Route Model Binding to simplify my code-> (house = House::FindOrFail($id);)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your function declaration is wrong. Please read and exercise about programming and specially PHP programming at first, Then try to work with frameworks such as Laravel or something else

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
public function show(House '$house')
{
        return view('house.show', compact('house'));
}
```

to this

```
public function show(House $house)
{
        return view('house.show', compact('house'));
}
```

Comment: after i change to new code, no error. but no data viewed in the form, should be viewing house data with id no 1: because the link is-> http://house.test/house/1

Answer (score 0):

Implicit binding works out of the box:

> ### Implicit Binding
>
> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or
>   controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route
>   segment name. For example:
>
> ```php
> Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
>     return $user->email;
> });
> ```
>
> Since the `$user` variable is type-hinted as the `App\User` Eloquent
>   model and the variable name matches the `{user}` URI segment, Laravel
>   will automatically inject the model instance that has an `ID` matching
>   the corresponding value from the request URI. If a matching model
>   instance is not found in the database, a `404` HTTP response will
>   automatically be generated.

But in case you want to declared explicitly, you can check the [Explicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding) of the documentation:

> ### Explicit Binding
>
> To register an explicit binding, use the router's model method to
>   specify the class for a given parameter. You should define your
>   explicit model bindings in the boot method of the 
>   `RouteServiceProvider` class:
>
> ```php
> public function boot()
> {
>     parent::boot();
>
>     Route::model('user', App\User::class);
> }
> ```
>
> Next, define a route that contains a `{user}` parameter:
>
> ```php
> Route::get('profile/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
>     //
> });
> ```
>
> Since we have bound all `{user}` parameters to the `App\User` model, a
>   `User` instance will be injected into the route. So, for example, a
>   request to `profile/1` will inject the Us`e`r instance from the
>   database which has an `ID` of `1`.
>
> If a matching model instance is not found in the database, a `404`
>   HTTP response will be automatically generated.

So, in your case:

**RouteServiceProvider.php**

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('house', App\House::class);
}
```

Then in your controller:

**HousesController.php**

```php
public function show(House $house)
{
        return view('house.show', compact('house'));
}
```

Comment: after i change to new code, no error. but no data viewed in the form, should be viewing house data with id no 1: because the link is-> http://house.test/house/1

Comment: @AndryWibowo tell us how your route is set up. It needs to be something like this: `GET /houses/{house}`